# Push values into array jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created an empty array at the beginning of the form

```
<script>
   var monthly_values = [];
   var i=0;
</script>
```

Inside the loop trying to achieve below code....
but the push doesn't work without "alert" box nor if i remove "ready(function())"

```
$prodline=500$    /// CGI script loops till 500 iterations 
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     i++;
     monthly_values.push("$premium$");
     setTimeout(function() { 
       alert("$premium$");
     }, 1);

 });
</script>
 $/prodline$//end of the iteration...
```

I push values from loop into array which is working .But i need to remove alert box or at least OK from alert box ..

The Entire Code is here..

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
       <title>PHP FILE  - $licensee$</title>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">   
       <meta name="Author" content="COMPULIFE Software, Inc.">
       <link href="../../css/styles_website.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="../../css/termsampler.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="../../css/$css$" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script>
         var monthly_values = [];
         var i=0;
    </script>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      //     var monthly_values = [];
         // var i=0;
    function getbest (ambest, company, compcode)
    {
      document.comparisonform.AmBest.value = ambest;
      document.comparisonform.CompanyName.value = company;
      document.comparisonform.CompanyCode.value = compcode;
      document.comparisonform.OnClick=abc=window.open('','reason','width=700,height=500,left=20,top=20,scrollbars=yes');
      document.comparisonform.target='reason';
      abc.focus();
      document.comparisonform.submit();
    }
    </script>  
    </head>
    <body>
    </tr>
    <style>
    .loader {
      border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

    @keyframes spin {
      0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="loader" style ></div>
    $prodline=500$

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        i++;
        monthly_values.push("$premium$");
        setTimeout(function() { 
          alert("$premium$"+"$company$"+"$product$"+"$healthcat$"+"$PremiumAnnual$"+"$Premium$"+"$rgpfpp$"+"$guar$"+"$policyfee$"+"$comp$"+"$prod$"+"$rowEvenOdd$");
        }, 1);

      });
    </script>
    $/prodline$
    </table>

    </form>

    <br><br>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        var len=monthly_values.length;
        var min_quote=monthly_values [0];
          var max_quote=monthly_values [monthly_values.length-1];

        window.location = 'http://loalhost/laravel/public/customised-quote?min_quote_val='+min_quote+'&max_quote_val='+max_quote;
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: what is `$premium$` and which type output you need

Comment: its float value eg. 73.35,104.40

Comment: "remove alert box or at least OK from alert box"... just remove alert from setTimeout

Comment: @Beginner that not php variable and its printing the values without any issues

Comment: maybe what he means is prepend

Comment: @undefined_variable if alert box is removed then the array is printing empty !! :(

Comment: please post your full code

Comment: what is this `$premium$`? it's neither php nor jquery variable (according to variable name rules). Please show complete code that what is this and how you get it

Comment: share your full code which will you tried

Comment: @Bhargav i have shared my entire code

Answer (score 1):

This code should work without problems, check the snippet below.
Are you including jQuery in your html?

```js
var monthly_values = [];
var i=0;
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
     i++;
     monthly_values.push("$premium$");
     setTimeout(function() { 
      console.log(monthly_values)
     }, 1);

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**  after seeing your updated code, if i understand it right, in your loop you are rendering the the document $(document).ready() snippet 500 times, which is completely wrong approach.

Not sure what language you are using, and what exactly are you trying to achieve with your loop, but you could just print your $prodline$ array directly into javascript array variable without having to loop through it

Also, now i noticed in your $(document).ready() at the end of your file you are redirecting to new url immediately, if this is your intended result, generate the array just before you redirect like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var monthly_values = []

$prodline=500$
    monthly_values.push("$premium$")
$/prodline$

    var len=monthly_values.length;
    var min_quote=monthly_values [0];
    var max_quote=monthly_values [monthly_values.length-1];

    window.location = 'http://localhost/laravel/public/customised-quote?min_quote_val='+min_quote+'&max_quote_val='+max_quote;

})
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry empty ARRAY :(

Comment: I don't see how it's empty I tried this snippet and this working fine

Comment: Please post your full code including the loop.  Are you trying to do this with PHP and $premium is a PHP variable?

Comment: yes i tired that at the end of operation im feting the first and last values from array where it give empty .. but practically this code should work ... and even if i remove alert it should work ...

Comment: @mike_t i have added the loop at the question thanks for your time

Comment: what scripting language is that?  See my updated answer

Comment: @mike_t Thanks for your time but same output :(

Comment: @mike_t you are right i did according to the standard procedure it was not working, accidentally the above my code i did it is working . is there any  possible way to remove  "OK" button from alert ?

Comment: @mike_t i tired the standard coding method but didnt work, accidentally this code worked ... yes its not the right syntax , but can i remove "OK" button from Alert box ...