# alert box without ok button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to show alert box without "OK" button and close after 2 seconds

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  alert("$premium$");
}, 1);
```

Comment: You can't alter the native alert()

Comment: you better use custom alerts , check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_alert.asp) for more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to amend the dialog shown by the standard `alert()` method as the buttons are controlled by the browser/OS.

If you need this behaviour you'll need to use a library which builds alert notifications in HTML which can be amended exactly as you require.

Comment: Thanks for your time is that possible ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345617/push-values-into-array-jquery  this is my issuse .... :( can you please help me on this else?

Comment: Is that question related to this one?

Comment: yes its related to it. i should push data into array , all those code written there irrespective of standard way and etc works with that only .. so like without alert box and document.ready etc which is not the right way to do it in my  code .

Comment: You seem to already have an answer in there. That question is completely unrelated to what you're asked here..

Comment: Is there a possible way to auto click ok ?

Comment: With the standard `alert()`, no.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own alertbox I think in vanilla CSS

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide buttons from native JavaScript dialogs. Your options depends on frameworks you are using. You can create custom dialogs with [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals) and many other frameworks.